# Cygwin executable not found even if existing

Tags: bash, cygwin, executable

I have recently been trying to install [Blackbox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox) on Cygwin, and as the docs say I did `cp ./blackbox/bin/* /usr/bin`.

Then I tried accessing it using `blackbox_edit`, and I get:

`/bin/bash: /usr/bin/blackbox_edit: No file or directory`

Same when I run `/usr/bin/blackbox_edit`. Running `stat /usr/bin/blackbox_edit` gives:

```
  File: /usr/bin/blackbox_edit
  Size: 958             Blocks: 4          IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: 671faeah/108133098d     Inode: 2251799814041428  Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (197609/   adrie)   Gid: (197609/   adrie)
Access: 2017-06-07 15:34:50.353508600 +0200
Modify: 2017-06-07 15:54:58.823472200 +0200
Change: 2017-06-07 15:59:00.592320500 +0200
 Birth: 2017-06-07 15:34:50.353508600 +0200
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I installed blackbox without problem.  But it requires `/usr/bin/env`.  Do a `stat` on that file.

Comment: Just checked, I do have it on my system.

Comment: Then that's not the problem.  Can you run from the directory you copied from: `./blackbox/bin/blackbox_edit`?

Comment: ```./blackbox_edit_start: ligne 2: $'\r' : command not found
./blackbox_edit_start: ligne 6: $'\r' : command not found
 : option non valable: ligne 7 : set: -
set : utilisation : set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o nom-option] [--] [arg ...]
: no such file or directory: blackbox_common.sh
./blackbox_edit_start: ligne 9: $'\r' : command not found
./blackbox_edit_start: ligne 15: syntax errr near symbol « $'do\r' »
'/blackbox_edit_start: ligne 15: `for param in "$@" ; do```

Comment: Try running `dos2unix` on the execuatbles.

Comment: Thanks about this. Indeed, git cloned them with `\r\n` instead of `\n`! I can now run them in the `blackbox/bin` and `/usr/bin` folders, using `./blackbox_xxx`, but still have the initial error: `No such file or directory` when trying to run them from anywhere, using `blackbox_xxx` or `/usr/bin/blackbox_xxx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it was a more obscure problem. To make it short, instead of running bash scripts with `/usr/bin/bash.exe`, cygwin was resolving `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` first (Ubuntu's bash).

Thanks anyways for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use GIT to get it.  Just go to [GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox), click on the big green button on the right that says, **Clone or download**.  Then click on **Download ZIP**.

That will download **blackbox_master.zip**.  Unzip it, then copy all the files in `blackbox_master/bin` to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I just tried and still not working. Apparently, even when I create a simple bash script in /usr/bin and try to run it from anywhere, it doesn't work. I correctly set up my CYGWIN_HOME and also added all bin folds to my path.

Comment: Try putting a simple script in `/usr/loca/bin`.  Does that work?

Comment: It doesn't, and it's pretty weird. `which test_script` -> `/usr/local/bin/test_script`. `test_script` -> `/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/test_script: No such file or directory`

Comment: How did you create `test_script`?